# Bash coding conventions

Tags: bash

I am trying to learn some Bash to maybe get a job working with computers one day.

To improve my clarity and disciple writing my self-learning code, I am trying to adhere to a set of consistent "guiding principles".

As I roll my own "guidelines" I obviously ask myself: should I not be using an established standard instead?

I could not find one such "authoritative" reference for Bash, similar to what these other languages have:

- Java (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)
  How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool
- Java (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language
- Java (https://code.google.com/p/java-coding-standards/wiki/Introduction) Google Java coding standards
- Python (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code
- Python (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html) Google Python Style Guide

#### Is there a link with a similar document for Bash which has good reason for being used?

Here is the type of stuff I was putting together on my own... but I think, especially as a beginner, I should be using guidelines written by experts rather than trying to come up with my own, as they would not be based on much experience, insight, practicality, knowledge of common patterns/anti-patterns, etc.

You may dispute the validity of such documents in general, but *some* people must like them for the web to have such prominent examples online as the ones I mention in the bullet-list above..

---

```
################################################################################    
# Coding conventions                                                                
#                                                                                   
# - Prefer lines of 80 characters of length or less                                 
#                                                                                   
# - Perform arithmetic operations and numeric comparisons within "(( ))" blocks     
#   e.g. if ((42<=24+24)), ((3**3==27))                                             
#                                                                                   
# - Reference variables by name, not expansion, within arithmetic evaluation        
#   e.g. ((i++)) rather than (($i++)), ((v+=42)) rathern than v=$(($v+42))          
#                                                                                   
# - Prefer "[[" to "[" for conditional expressions                                  
#                                                                                   
# - Prefer "[[ $s ]]" to "[[ -n $s ]]" when checking for empty strings              
#                                                                                   
# - Document each function with at least a summary sentence. This should not        
#   exceed the preferred line length, be written in third person, end with a        
#   period and concisely describe the general utility of the function   
#
# ...
# ...
# ...
#            
################################################################################
```

---

Comment: People may prefer different styles and here's [one example](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/style), and [another](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-bash/StyleGuideShell.en.pdf).

Comment: Of course people may prefer different styles. I believe if an argument can be made for the Google Python Style Guide to exist, a similar one may be made for a Bash equivalent. In that light, and for those people who find these standards useful, I thought that picking a reasonable on would help.

Comment: Most of those guidelines should be exactly reversed. As is, they do nothing but create unportable bash-specific scripts. **Don't learn bash programming. Learn *shell* programming.** If there's on best practice, it is sticking to POSIX as much as you can.

Comment: Given your many posts on the topic of `bash` programming, you seem to be placing an undue importance on the topic. I doubt you are going to find a job where shell programming is your primary duty; an in-depth knowledge of `bash` can make everyday tasks easier, but it's not going to be the primary reason you are hired. Style guides for Python exist to provide consistency for projects with many contributors or projects whose long lifetime suggests they will be maintained by people not involved with earlier development. Similar projects written in `bash` are rare.

Comment: On the other side of @chepner's coin is the fact that true experts in shell scripting are likewise rare. If you set out to learn shell scripting or even specifically BASH, keep going. Don't let us talk you out of it. Shell scripting may not serve you in your career in a direct way, but there are few enough people that know it well and far too many who only think they know it. Even in the abstract it's a useful thing to understand.

Comment: @chepner: To eventually be hired, I set myself these goals: learn `bash` to be fast and _accurate_ on the command line, learn `python` to write my scripts, learn `java` to do my GUIs (SWT), learn `android` to do my mobile apps, learn `linux` to do my sysadmin, learn machine learning to do my back-end stuff (I have ideas), learn html5/css/jscript to do some, probably _very little_ web presentation, as in "a little web site for myself", learn _algorithms_ and compete in a few TopCoder tournaments to get some interviewing practice. Bash is just my 1st step: foundations and not looking silly @ CLI

Comment: @chepner: scanning the Python style guidelines I have also found good tips for "general software engineering", e.g. don't pollute the global namespace (I can apply that to Bash's globals too, although it's slightly different), leverage shortcut comparison operators, watch out for file-based race conditions, etc. I find these docs useful if read for inspiration.. or as an "asynchronous" chat with a knowledgeable practitioner who decided to share some of his insights for others to benefit from> A bit like what you do here, chepner, sharing your vast knowledge of Bash with the "forum"..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## My shell scripting standards

1. Prefer portability, but don't sacrifice security and whitespace awareness to it.
2. Prefer builtins over external commands.
3. But, use fast external commands to process very large inputs.
4. Avoid unnecessary subshells and pipelines.
5. Don't preoptimize.
6. Learn the rules of quoting. Then, use quotes.
7. Use functions to improve readability and control scope.
8. Don't give scripts silly file extensions.
9. Never change directory without checking that it worked.
10. Eschew hobgoblins

> A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by
>   little statesmen and philosophers and divines.
>
> – Ralph Waldo Emerson

### When to ignore the portability rule

1. Use `-execdir` when appropriate with `find`.
2. Use `null` separators when the toolset allows to avoid accidentally wordsplitting on whitespace.
3. Learn all the glob extensions and use them.
4. If your target systems all have BASH, don't bend over backwards to be POSIXLY_STRICT.
5. Use here strings.

Comment: I am accepting this great answer, thanks! :) I am curious: what would you consider _silly_ extensions, as in your point `#8`? My favourite of all: use `\0`!

Comment: @Robottinosino Any extension is silly for a shell script. Some editors insist everything needs an extension, so they put `.sh` after shell and bash scripts. Of course, having the *same* extension for different kinds of scripts (sh, bash, ksh, zsh, csh, tsh…) is even sillier, because it leaves you with the erroneous impression they can all be invoked the same way.

Comment: Oh, I don't feel that way, then. But your other points are good and now adopted by me as well! :)

Comment: @Robottinosino it's not a feeling. Take a look in /usr/bin. Grep for '/bin/bash'. Tell me how many of those scripts have extensions. How about the ones with `/bin/sh`? Extensions are a windows-ism, but you want your scripts to be like shell commands themselves. It ruins the semantics of shell commands if they end in .sh.

Comment: Basically _no_ shell scripts bear the `.sh` extension, you are very right about that! I don't mind the explicitness of it though, as I only prepare "own scripts". You absolutely convinced me about system-level scripts though. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The best bash style guide I have come across [is from Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml).

There is also some additional advice [from the Chromium project](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/styleguide/shell.md).

For learning bash, the [Apple Developer Shell Scripting primer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html) is excellent.

Using a style guide for bash is rather sensible, as it is full of tricks and unexpected and difficult to diagnose quirks. Thus, if you follow the same style all the time, you should only fall for each of those tricks once.

Comment: While the currently accepted argument has some really good rules, they don't seem to be a reference to anything widely accepted and used. This answer improves on that.